# A question about divisibility of sum of two consecutive primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I was curious about the sum of two consecutive primes and after proving that [the sum for the odd primes always has at least 3 prime divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/941928), I came up with this question:

> Find the least natural number $k$ so that there will be only a finite
> number of $2$ consecutive primes whose sum is divisible by $k$.

Although I couldn't go anywhere on finding $k$, I could prove the number isn't $1, 2, 3, 4$ or $6$, just with proving there are infinitely many primes $P_n$ so that $k|P_n+P_{n+1}$ and $k$ is one of $1, 2, 3, 4, 6$:

The cases of $k=1$ and $k=2$ are trivial. The case of $k=3$, I prove as follows:

Suppose there are only a finite number of primes $P_k$ so that $3|P_k+P_{k+1}$ .We can conclude there exists the largest prime number $P_m$ so that $3|P_m+P_{m-1}$ and thus, for every prime number $P_n$ where $n>m$, we know that $P_n+P_{n+1}$ does **not** divide $3$. We also know that for every prime number $p$ larger than $3$ we have: $p \equiv 1 \pmod 3$  or $p \equiv 2 \pmod 3$. According to this we can say for every natural number $n>m$, we have either $P_n \equiv P_{n+1} \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ or $P_n \equiv P_{n+1} \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, because otherwise, $3|P_n+P_{n+1}$ which is not true. Now according to Dirichlet's Theorem, we do have infinitely many primes congruent to $2$ or $1$, mod $3$. So our case can't be true because of it.

We can prove the case of $k=4$ and $k=6$ with the exact same method, but I couldn't find any other method for proving the result for other $k$.

Comment: this is a very nice question and it will seem weird if there exists such a $k$

Comment: Thanks, I myself think such a $k$ doesn't exist too, but proving it is another matter :P

Comment: I think Schinzel's Hypothesis says it's true though.

Comment: I also doubt that this is going to be answered.why don't you try posting this to http://mathoverflow.net/?

Comment: @CODE: Indeed, Schinzel's Hypothesis H implies it. In fact you don't even need that much: Dickson's conjecture suffices, with some cleverness.

Comment: You can make a kind of a prime counting function that counts the pairs of consecutive primes divisible by $k$ below $n$. Maybe call it $\pi_k(n)$. After doing some computations it seems that $\pi_k(n) \sim c Li(n)$ for some constant $c$ which for a lot of $k$'s looks to be close to $1/\phi(k)$

Comment: @ghosts not true, $12$ does not divide $103+107$, for instance.

Comment: A particular case of Dirichlet's Theorem is that there are infinitely many primes congruent to 1 mod 3 and  infintely many congruent to 2 mod 3. But Dirichlet's Theoerem does NOT say anything about CONSECUTIVE primes. Your reasoning for k=3 is invalid. ... However it is a good Q, and, I suspect, with no known A.

Comment: 3+ years and no A. Maybe put it on MathOverflow and see what the pros say.

Comment: @user254665 my reasoning for k=3 says that if the hypothesis is false, from some point on we would have all prime numbers are either congruent to 2 mod 3 or 1 mod 3, THAT can't be true according to Dirichlet's Theorem.

Comment: My apologies. You are right.

Comment: The question amounts to : does there exist a k, such that, only finitely many pairs of consecutive primes are additive inverses mod k.

Comment: @CODE has this been crossposted to Math Overflow?

Comment: @RomainS [It has, but no answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145263/a-question-about-the-divisibility-of-sum-of-2-consecutive-primes).

Comment: The link to Yahoo Answers shut down today. Can you link elsewhere?

Comment: Anecdotally, there are a plethora of numbers that never divide the sum of twin primes, which are consecutive primes: $11,13,19,31,43, \dots$. However, these numbers may well divide the sums of other consecutive primes.

Comment: @CODE: I'm just curious, isn't $k=2$ the answer?, of course this is except for $2 + 3$.

Comment: @KeithBackman late response, but surely that can't be true:  Schinzel's hypothesis H implies that for all $n$, there are infinitely many pairs of twin primes of the form $kn \pm 1$.  For example, $11$ divides $197+199$, $13$ divides $311+313$, $19$ divides $227+229$, etc.

Comment: OP, your first link goes to some weird Yahoo page.  Please fix.   Ty

Comment: [Easily to check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%28k%3D2%20to%20999%29%20%5Bprod_%28n%3D2%20to%205000%29%7Bsign%5B%28prime%5Bn%5D%2Bprime%5Bn%2B1%5D%29%20mod%20k%20%5D%7D%5D) that each of the described sums for $n\in[2,5000]\;$ has one or more dividers among $\pi(k),\; k\in[2, 999].$

That's why the required k should be too big.